# Is there any other OS that use PE file or atleast a chance to use it in future?

Tags: .net, operating-system, portable-executable

> Regardless of which compiler you use to compile the .NET language ,
>   the result is a managed module. A managed module is a standard Windows
>   portable executable (PE) file that requires the CLR to execute. **"In
>   the future, other operating systems may use the PE file format as
>   well."**

has any other started supporting the use of PE file or atleast a chance to support it in future?
Other than .NET does any other framework(J2EE,etc) produce PE?
What are the counterparts to PE?

Comment: The PE for .NET is primarily just wrapping. Hence, mono on linux will load a PE - does that count?

Comment: .NET PE can be run on all Linux loaded machines?

Comment: assuming the managed code doesn't attempt to use Windows-only features (winforms, the registry, etc), and assuming the machine has mono installed, sure; IIRC Ubuntu includes mono by default. The mono BCL is a pretty good subset of the MS BCL.

Comment: So isnt .NET cross platform? i havent seen anybody mentioning that

Comment: The CLI as a technology is cross-platform - see: Mono, Silverlight / Moonlight, XNA (on xbox for example), WP7, CF, MF (on watches etc). However, ".NET" refers to the MS implementation of the CLI. If you stick to cross-platform parts of the stack, then yes: it can be cross-platform!

Comment: .NET as whole is MS owned. But languages independently are open source and cross platform?

Comment: Languages are languages. C# is a public spec (ECMA/ISO), and there is a declaration re the CLI. The MS **implementation** is not open-source, however, the CLI **specification** is again, open, and there are open-source implementations (such as Mono).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notes**

If you really wanted to know which other platforms apart from Windows support .NET/managed executables, then your question is a bit to broad or a little misleading when asking about the PE format.

The PE file format is basically just that, a file format. Currently it is being used two serve to primary purposes:

1. The file format that (native) executables use on Windows 32bit and 64bit platforms.
2. The file format that .NET (managed) executables use.

The following list includes examples for both uses. More specifically, only Mono uses it as in the second case above (and not in the first). All others use it in the sense of the first case above (and not in the second).

Why Microsoft choose the PE file format for .NET? Possibly, because they had all the infrastructure (loading, etc.) in place already, and only needed to bolt on something for .NET. For example, with .NET (on Windows) one doesn't have to use some sort of loader command to start the application, like `java.exe -jar ...` or `python.exe ...`, but can start and launch it as it were a native executable.

Illustrated oversimplified, a .NET PE file only contains one reference to `mscoree.dll` which will then take on the loading and execution of the contained MSIL code as a managed application.

**Uses**

[ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org) should also use the PE format (and not just as a container for a .NET assembly), 
as it is supposed to be binary compatible with Microsoft Windows (NT).

**Update**

Actually, when you Google "pe file format" the first link that comes up is [this Wikipedia article about the PE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Use_on_other_operating_systems). It has a section about uses of the file format, which basically contains the following:

- ReactOS
- BeOS R3 and SkyOS (historically; which have moved to ELF however)
- MacOS X 10.5 (but not binary compatible with Windows)

Not real Operating Systems in the true sense, but nevertheless:

- Mono. One or two differences to the other uses should be noted here

  1. Mono ([by default, on Linux you can register it as a non native binary](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications)) requires the application to be started using the `mono` command. So you *could* argue that in this case it is not really the OS that supports the PE format (much like it doesn't support PHP scripts or whatever). But this is a arguable and possibly irrelevant point indeed.
  2. It can only handle PE files "for .NET".
- Emulators: Wine, HX DOS Extender

Note that OS/2 (2.x and higher) does not use PE, even though historically it probably could have (given it's and NT's common history). It uses the [linear executable file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE).

Comment: so i think i should rather change my question to which all os do not support PE?

Comment: Doesnt excution of pe require CLR? does all these os have clr preloaded?

Comment: As @Marc Gravell has hinted on in his comments, the PE format (today) servers basically two purposes: (a) the file format for native binaries (i.e. not .NET based) on Windows platforms (b) a container/stub that merely contains a .NET assembly - only this one would require a CLR implementation (currently Microsoft .NET or Mono). My answer and Wikipedia includes examples for both.

Comment: i was expecting  more popular OS s

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft .NET is about about Windows, and is not cross platform. Mono is a cross platform implementation of CLR standards, which can executable .NET assemblies (in PE format) on the operating systems it supports (Windows, OS X, and many others).

Mono compilers (C#/VB.NET) also emit assemblies in PE format to be compatible with Microsoft .NET.

PE counterparts are too many. Java uses JAR. Android uses APK.

Comment: So if you use MONO you can execute .NET application in all the OSs?

Comment: The reverse is true that Mono applications are also .NET friendly. However, .NET has too many Windows only stuffs that prevents some applications from being Mono friendly, http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical